# Flutter/Dart DateTime parsing UTC and converting to local

Tags: dart

I am trying to parse a UTC Date string to `DateTime` and then parse it to local, however I am having troubles with converting it to the local time. In the UK it should be plus one, however when I print `.isUtc` it returns as false.

This is what I have now:

```dart
print(widget.asset.purchaseDate);
DateTime temp = DateTime.parse(widget.asset.purchaseDate);
print(temp.toLocal());
```

```
I/flutter (5434): 2020-05-07 21:29:00
I/flutter (5434): 2020-05-07 21:29:00.000
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to indicate a timezone to `DateTime.parse`, otherwise it assumes local time. From the dartdoc:

> An optional time-zone offset part, possibly separated from the
>   previous by a space. The time zone is either 'z' or 'Z', or it is a
>   signed two digit hour part and an optional two digit minute part.

Since you know your string represents UTC, you can tell the parser by adding the `Z` suffix.

```
var temp = DateTime.parse(widget.asset.purchaseDate + 'Z');
print(temp.isUtc); // prints true
```

Comment: Z was the key. Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

While [@Richard Heap's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61669980/2837443) answer stands I'd like `DateTime.parseUtc()` to exist.

If there will be a day when dart allows static extension methods here is an implementation that would work:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  static DateTime parseUtc(String formattedDate) => DateTime.parse('${formattedDate}z');

  static DateTime? tryParseUtc(String? formattedDate) {
    if (formattedDate != null) {
      return DateTime.tryParse('${formattedDate}z');
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Currently you'd have to use it with the extension classes name, like so:
`DateTimeExtension.parseUtc(someDate)`
or
`DateTimeExtension.tryParseUtc(someOtherDate)`

I think the latter is more useful where `someOtherDate` is `nullable`