# Dart datetime parse why I'm getting wrong value?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to parse a `DateTime` from a response of a JSON object

```
print(DateTime.parse("2022-07-05T15:11:44+09:00"));
```

Getting output:

```
2022-07-05 06:11:44.000Z
```

Desired output:

```
2022-07-05 03:11:44.000Z
```

How I will get the desired output?

Comment: I think you should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668530/flutter-dart-datetime-parsing-utc-and-converting-to-local

Comment: The +9:00 means 9 hours ahead of UTC time. You therefore would subtract 9 hours from that local time to get the UTC time, and 15 - 9 = 6.  Why would you expect 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [`.toLocal()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/toLocal.html):

```dart
void main() {
    print(DateTime.parse('2022-07-05 06:11:44.000Z').toLocal());
}
```

Comment: The reason for this behavior is that Dart (like JavaScript) has only two available time zones: Local time and UTC time. When you ask for the time-zone offset `+09:00`, the parser assumes it can't represent that, and converts it to UTC time. If there is a time zone offset in the input, syntactically, no matter which hours and minutes, the result becomes UTC. Even if the requested time zone offset happens to match the current local time zone. Anything else would just be too unpredictable. So, if you want local time, you need to call `toLocal` after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You parse local time, Dart return UTC time